# Can a HTTPServlet be part of the View Component?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, model-view-controller

I want to program a application implementing MVC using a Swing-View and a HTML-View.

I found several descriptions on how to use MVC for native desktop-applications and how to use it on web applications- but not for both.

For web applications, it seems quite common that the servlet itself is the controller. This however would mean that the controller (which should be independend from the chosen view, at least as I understand it) cannot be used for the swing-view any more.

Because of this I would see the servlet in this case as a part of the view, which on the one hand handles the redicting to the correct html-page, on the other hand reads the input from the user and forwards it to the controller.

As there is no *best* solution, what would your approach to the problem be?

Comment: Essentially, they are both in the same, but what you have is the Swing/`JEditorPane` is acting as the browser.  The Web MVC would then, remain unchanged.

Comment: I would rather be interested in the general aproach instead of the actual implementation. I figured, my question was if it makes sense to use the passive-view pattern (which would place the business logic in the controller and therefore make it and the model reusable) instead of the classic MVC pattern (which would place the business logic in the model, making only the model reusable)

Comment: The issue is, that both sides are there own MVC.  Having said that, the `JEditorPane` (via the html), would be the view, with the server acting as the controller and managing the model, as is most web apps.  MVC isn't just one big umbrella, you can have small implementations within larger ones